# Zoom when clicking on photo

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

On http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/application I can click on a photo to zoom/enlarge the photo.

How can I obtain this functionality? I know the theme is meant to be bought but I don't want to buy it for just this feature.

I guess it's quite but maybe there already exists libraries to obtain this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Theme use [Zoom.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Medium-Style-Image-Zoom-Plugin-with-jQuery-zoom-js/), you need to include the script and set `data-action="zoom`" at your image

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript you can do this with CSS3 transitions.

See snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pic-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0;
  /*animation*/
  
  animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:-1;
  background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-2 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Beautiful-Wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-3 {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpaperbackgrounds.org/photo/1362384578166_[hdwallpaperbackgrounds.org].jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-4 {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  background: url(https://www.colourbox.com/preview/3210731-spring-beautiful-red-tulip-flowers-nature-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* keyframes*/

@keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
  }    
 }

@-o-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
</div>
```